# Issue with jQuery $.get() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, get

I am working on a small chat application that uses jQuery to get some info from a PHP file.
The output of the file is a whole bunch of HTML data.

The script works just fine in FF but not in Internet (f***ing) Explorer, lol.
The code looks like this:

```
$.get("index.php", {p: "chatData", type: "regular"}, function(data){
     startPoint = data.indexOf("|START-POINT|");
     endPoint = data.indexOf("|END-POINT|");
     dataReturn = data.substring(startPoint, endPoint);
});
```

The thing is, that I have to access some SESSION variables inside my chatData.php file.
Therefore I call index.php with p-varable, that includes chatData.php into my index.php file where the SESSION variables is set. This is maybe not the best sollution, but I couldn't think of another way to access the SESSION variables. Anyway.

But when I'm doing like this, the callback will contain all html from index.php as well, but I only want the data from chatData.php, so therefore I put these start- and endPoints into the code, so it can do substring and get the desired data that way. Same thing here, maybe not the best sollution...

**But now the issue!**
The callback data only contains the html from index.php, it sould be the index.php html + the chatData html... But I think the issue lies in this index.php inclusion, because if I call the file like usual, I will get the data (tho, as I said, I need the SESSION variables from index.php as well...).

So why doesn't this work in IE, but just fine in other broswers such as FF ?

**EDIT:** The problem is solved. The problem was my START-POINTS in my php file, they were wrongly placed... Sorry about that noobish misstake. Thank yuo anyway!

Comment: Since that's basically what vava said, you should choose his answer instead of putting an edit on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that index.php get those parameters you sent to it and include your other file? Just seems like it doesn't, HTML can't magically disappear :) Maybe IE set it as $_POST variables as opposed to Firefox that does it through $_GET or something.